# AngularJS: Directive - Attributes null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, attributes, null, directive

I'm new to Angular and after a few weeks of struggling through it now I ran into a problem i cannot solve.
So now I'm asking this question here hopeing somebody can help me or give me a hint :)

My Problem is located on a custom directive. The directive expects 6 Attributes. 5 of them a simple Strings or Numbers. One is an Array, containing JSON-Objects which is loaded before from a REST-Service in the Controller. So now the Problem is, that the directive only gets 3 of them with its value and the others as null. I've tried observing the Attributes with $observe but that didn't work. So now I am at my wit's end and hope somebody has THE ANSWER :D Many thanks in advance!

### DIRECTIVE (simplyfied)

```
myAppDirectives.directive('myDirective',['aService', function(aService) {
            return {

                restrict : 'E',

                scope : {
                    a: '@',
                    b: '@',
                    c: '@',
                    d: '@',
                    e: '@',
                    f: '@'
                },

                link : function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {   
                    console.log(attrs.a);
                    console.log(attrs.b);
                    console.log(attrs.c);
                    console.log(attrs.d);
                    console.log(attrs.e);
                    console.log(attrs.f);

                    attrs.$observe('a', function(value) {
                        console.log('a has changed value to ' + value);
                    });
                    attrs.$observe('b', function(value) {
                        console.log('b has changed value to ' + value);
                    });
                    attrs.$observe('c', function(value) {
                        console.log('c has changed value to ' + value);
                    });
                    attrs.$observe('d', function(value) {
                        console.log('d has changed value to ' + value);
                    });
                    attrs.$observe('e', function(value) {
                        console.log('e has changed value to ' + value);
                    });
                    attrs.$observe('f', function(value) {
                        console.log('f has changed value to ' + value);
                    });
                }
    }]);
```

### HTML-SNIPPET

```
         <my-Directive a="{{a}}" 
                       b="{{b}}" 
                       c="{{c}}" 
                       d="{{d}}"
                       e="{{e}}" 
                       f="{{f}}">
            </my-Directive>
```

### CONTROLLER-SNIPPET (simplyfied the $http-Call)

```
$scope.a= 200;
$scope.b= 250;
$scope.c= -1;
$scope.d= 'Doret';
$scope.e= 100;
$scope.f= [{"a":"Lorem","b":1},{"a":"Ipsum","b":2}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attributes receiving null values, are their names of mixed case? If so could you try simple cased names?